# No information from the .log file about unresolved references

Tags: errors, cross-referencing

In October 2013 (question 136902), it was asked where one can explicitly find unresolved references in one's LaTeX encoding. The reply was: in your .log file.

This used to be the correct and helpful answer in the past. But today I found that it is no longer true: I run (on *ubuntu 14.04*)

*LaTeX Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=latex 2014.9.13)*

with the editor

*GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7) of 2014-03-07 on toyol, modified by Debian*

Today I merged files (which made no problems when separate) and ran LaTeX. I got the error message that "There were unresolved references". I looked into the .log file to see what had happened. The only line concerning my error message, almost at the end, was the following:

"**LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.**"

That was all. No specification at all. That used to be different. I feel completely left alone with a dvi file of 153 pages. What can I do?

Comment: Compiling twice did not remove the **warning** message?

Comment: No, not even three or four times.

Comment: Can you post the `.log` file ?

Comment: Would part of be enough? It is 1.1 MB! (Reason: I still use the old \rm \sf etc throughout the document).

Comment: LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14587 strings out of 494296
 257182 string characters out of 6166962
 445520 words of memory out of 5000000
 17497 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 28648 words of font info for 105 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 517 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 65i,26n,71p,1472b,596s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on alg.int.dvi (153 pages, 865952 bytes).

Comment: You shouldn't use `\rm`: it has been deprecated for more than twenty years.

Comment: @egreg I know but it does not concern the question. And it is not for more than twenty years, but it is true that the merged files have a long tradition. - Do you think this is connected with the error of nonresolved references? *This* was the reason for my question.

Comment: @HartmutLaue No, that's completely independent. By the way, LaTeX2e was released in June 1994, which makes almost 22 years. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I plant `\ref{test}` in a file that has no `\label{test}`, I get *two* warnings in the log file. First

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `test' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.
```

that shows where the problematic `\ref` is to be found, then

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

at the end of the run.

If I run

```
texloganalyser -w test.log
```

I get

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `test' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

which is a nice way for coping with warnings.

The same information is printed on the terminal if I issue

```
grep undefined lucibug.log | grep '[Rr]eference'
```

Comment: Great! That was helpful. The first line you gave was indeed hidden right in the middle of the (long) .log file. I have not had this kind of error for years, therefore forgot that the specification is *before* the general warning. Thanks a lot. And, in a sense, it is true that those old commands played an indirect role: Without them, the .log file would be much much shorter... - I'll have to replace them by Search/Replace. Thank you for helping me.